# Cartesian equation of the locus

Tags: geometry

I have the question "Find the Cartesian equation of the locus of the set of points P in each case.

P is equidistant from the point (4,1) and the line X = -2"

So I know that PA = PB.
And so (X+4)^2 + (Y+1)^2 = (X-2)^2

I am not quite sure what to do after this.

Comment: Your expression is incorrect. 

Using distance formula on the LHS and intuition for the RHS, we obtain

$(x-4)^2+(y-1)^2=(x+2)^2$ 

and then that is literally the locus, you just need to find a nicer form for it - which is done by expanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

For a point $P=(x,y)$, the distance $PA$ is:
$$
PA=\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y-1)^2}
$$
and the distance from the line $l$ of equation $x=-2$ is $Pl= |x+2|$

And note that this locus is, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola), a parabola.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(4,1)$ and let $B$ be the point where a horizontal line can be drawn from $P$ to meet $B$ on the line $x=-2$ (as this is the shortest distance, and hence the distance that we will use.

$PA=PB$

$(PA)^2=(PB)^2$

where $(PA)^2=(x-4)^2 + (y-1)^2$ (distance formula)

and $(PB)^2=(x+2)^2 + (y-y)^2=(x+2)^2$    (squaring avoids any absolute sign errors)

so we get $(x-4)^2+(y-1)^2=(x+2)^2$

Now we simply expand both sides (intuition tells me to keep y as it is) :

$x^2-8x+16+(y-1)^2=x^2+4x+4$
which arrives at:
$$(y-1)^2=12(x-1)$$

so geometrically this locus is a parabola.